# find item in dropdownlist and set it to selected in .asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get data from session and  find the selected value on my drowdownlist and set it to selected in asp.net razor MVC

update 
what I'm trying to do this in MVC you know this trick in WebForm

```
dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

just I want to know I can you do it in MVC

```
ForecastReportModel forecast = (ForecastReportModel)Session["forecastReportRange"];
```

my quistion how to find selected value in dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.startMonth, new SelectList(Model.getMonths(), "Value", "Key", "Start Month",forecast.startMonth), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Does the forecast.startMonth have a value already?

Comment: Can you put the getMonths method?

Comment: public int startMonth { get; set; }

Comment: No, i mean this one: Model.getMonths()

Comment: sorry I don't have getMonths

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question. Could you clarify what you are doing? I ask as if you have a model you are using in a view and it looks like you have then using the "DropDownListFor" and specifying the property you want the selected drop down value to be bound to on the post back should be sufficient for your needs yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectList has a field for the selected value, mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725506(v=vs.118).aspx) (other overrides available too).  You need to supply the selected value in order for the selection to occur.  So it works differently from web forms.